# Subset variables in data frame based on column type

Tags: r

I need to subset data frame based on column type - for example from data frame with 100 columns I need to keep only those column with type `factor` or `integer`. I've written a short function to do this, but is there any simpler solution or some built-in function or package on CRAN?

My current solution to get variable names with requested types:

```
varlist <- function(df=NULL, vartypes=NULL) {
  type_function <- c("is.factor","is.integer","is.numeric","is.character","is.double","is.logical")
  names(type_function) <- c("factor","integer","numeric","character","double","logical")
  names(df)[as.logical(sapply(lapply(names(df), function(y) sapply(type_function[names(type_function) %in% vartypes], function(x) do.call(x,list(df[[y]])))),sum))]  
}
```

The function `varlist` works as follows:

1. For every requested type and for every column in data frame call "is.TYPE" function
2. Sum tests for every variable (boolean is casted to integer automatically)
3. Cast result to logical vector
4. subset names in data frame

And some data to test it:

```
df <- read.table(file="http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/statlog/german/german.data", sep=" ", header=FALSE, stringsAsFactors=TRUE)
names(df) <- c('ca_status','duration','credit_history','purpose','credit_amount','savings', 'present_employment_since','installment_rate_income','status_sex','other_debtors','present_residence_since','property','age','other_installment','housing','existing_credits', 'job','liable_maintenance_people','telephone','foreign_worker','gb')
df$gb <- ifelse(df$gb == 2, FALSE, TRUE)
df$property <- as.character(df$property)
varlist(df, c("integer","logical"))
```

I'm asking because my code looks really cryptic and hard to understand (even for me and I've finished the function 10 minutes ago).

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand your question, but why not just something like `df[sapply(df, function(x) is.integer(x) || is.logical(x))]`?

Comment: I do this kind of subsetting frequently, that is why I've tried to create this function - to simplify my life.

Comment: Btw., why do you have to include downloading this rather big data.frame in your reproducible example? Next time you should just use one of the build-in datasets.

Comment: @Roland Noted. What built-in dataset with many columns and with many data types would you recommend? From my point of view the dataset is really small, just 78KB, but I'll try to choose smaller next time.

Comment: I would have used the iris dataset and made one of the numeric columns integer. I dislike downloading data for security reasons and it also isn't guaranteed that the data will be available for download in the future.

Comment: @TomasGreif, you can take any of them and add the code to convert to different types as part of your minimal example.

Comment: @Roland: OK, modified iris would be good choice. Are there really any security issues? In general, I do agree that availability of external dataset is not guaranteed (and I won't use it next time), however this specific dataset is available at this URL since 1994.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
subset_colclasses <- function(DF, colclasses="numeric") {
  DF[,sapply(DF, function(vec, test) class(vec) %in% test, test=colclasses)]
}

str(subset_colclasses(df, c("factor", "integer")))
```

Answer (score 19):

Just do the following:

```
df[,sapply(df,is.factor) | sapply(df,is.integer)]
```

Comment: how would I do something like   df[,sapply(df,!is.list)] ????  (get all columns that are NOT list)

Comment: @userJT `df[, sapply(df, function(x) !is.list(x))]`

Comment: I also found out in the meantime that this worked df2<-df[,!sapply(df,is.list)]

Comment: Is it possible to select continuous data (exclude integer)?