# Select columns based on classes/types with compatibility for dplyr::select

Tags: r, class, select, dplyr

### Actual question

How do I define a select helper that selects columns based on their class/type and that is also compatible with `dplyr`'s architecture?

### Due dilligence

I've looked at https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/introduction.html and the help for `dplyr::select_helpers` but didn't find anything that would allow me to select based on classes/types

### Example

Bring in some variation WRT classes/types:

```
dat <- mtcars
dat <- dat %>% mutate(
  mpg = as.character(mpg),
  wt = as.factor(wt),
  vs = as.character(vs)
)
```

In short, I would like to make this a generic approach for *all* possible classes/types (and combinations of them) in R:

```
dat[ , sapply(dat, is.character)]
# mpg    wt vs
# 1    21  2.62  0
# 2    21 2.875  0
# 3  22.8  2.32  1
# 4  21.4 3.215  1
```

Based on [Subset variables in data frame based on column type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17964513/subset-variables-in-data-frame-based-on-column-type) I could do it like this:

```
select_on_class <- function(.data, cls = "numeric") {
  dat[ , names(.data)[sapply(.data,
    function(vec, clss) class(vec) %in% clss, clss = cls)]]
}
dat %>% select_on_class(c("character", "factor"))
# mpg    wt vs
# 1    21  2.62  0
# 2    21 2.875  0
# 3  22.8  2.32  1
# 4  21.4 3.215  1
```

But I would like to be able to use it in calls to `dplyr::select`, so I tried this:

```
has_class <- function(.data, cls = "numeric") {
  nms <- names(.data)[sapply(.data,
    function(vec, clss) class(vec) %in% clss, clss = cls)]
  sapply(nms, as.name)
}
dat %>% has_class(c("character", "factor"))
# $mpg
# mpg
# 
# $wt
# wt
# 
# $vs
# vs
```

The problem is that `sapply(nms, as.name)` returns a `list` and that doesn't play nicely with the internals of `select` (which I don't completely understand yet, BTW):

```
dat %>% select(has_class(c("character", "factor")))
# Error: All select() inputs must resolve to integer column positions.
# The following do not:
#   *  has_class("character")

dat %>% select_(has_class(c("character", "factor")))
# Error in UseMethod("as.lazy") : 
#   no applicable method for 'as.lazy' applied to an object of class "list"
```

---

### EDIT

Based on the answer using `select_if` I tried to generalize and got stuck:

```
has_class <- function(.data, cls) {
  sapply(.data, function(vec, clss) class(vec) %in% clss, clss = cls)
}
dat %>% has_class(c("character", "factor"))
# mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
# TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
dat %>% select_if(has_class, c("character", "factor"))
# Error in vapply(tbl, p, logical(1), ...) : values must be length 1,
# but FUN(X[[1]]) result is length 32
```

AFAIU, the `.predicate` functions just needs to return a logical vector (which `has_class` does) and I can pass additional arguments to the `.predicate` functions via `...` (which I did). So where am I still going wrong?

Comment: `dat %>% select(which(sapply(., is.character)))` might be another option

Comment: @docendodiscimus: nice one! Haven't thought of this option. Still not "completely the `dplyr` selection helper way", but at least a nice workaround. Thx for sharing!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think `dplyr::select_if()` may be what you are looking for. For example

```
dat <- mtcars %>% 
       mutate(mpg = as.character(mpg),
              wt = as.character(wt),
              vs = as.character(vs)
       ) %>% 
       select_if(is.character)
```

Comment: Cool, didn't know `select_if` yet! Thanks!

Comment: Still not completely satisfied yet ;-) Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong when trying to generalize `is.character` to a custom `.predicate` function (see edit and also take note that I changed the class of `wt` to `factor`)?

Comment: @Rappster Think about how you would use `is.character` with `select_if` -  each column in the dataset is passed to `is.character` separately by `select_if`. So by analogy, `has_class` must be a function that takes columns (vectors), not datasets. So you need `has_class` to apply to a single column too. Therefore, use `has_class <- function(vec, clss){ class(vec) %in% clss}` instead

Answer (score 3):

If instead of list, we can return a character vector form our custom function, then we can use `one_of`:

```
has_class_v1 <- function(.data, cls = "numeric") {
  names(.data)[sapply(.data,
                      function(vec, clss) class(vec) %in% clss, clss = cls)]
  }

has_class_v1(dat, "character")
# [1] "mpg" "wt"  "vs" 

# use one_of
dat %>%
  select(one_of(has_class_v1(.,"character"))) %>% 
  head
#    mpg    wt vs
# 1   21  2.62  0
# 2   21 2.875  0
# 3 22.8  2.32  1
# 4 21.4 3.215  1
# 5 18.7  3.44  0
# 6 18.1  3.46  1
```

Comment: Never used `one_of` before, also a nice workaround! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The most streamlined and generalisable way of achieving this in my opinion while leveraging `dplyr` would be to use `dplyr::select_if` but in a more direct way than the one suggested by @wjchulme (although a nice trick) :

```
dat %>%
select_if(sapply(., class) %in% c("numeric", "character"))
```

And so on, with more classes if needed. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

The `dplyr` package added the  `where()` function sometime after the answer in 2018. Here's the [link](https://tidyselect.r-lib.org/reference/where.html) to the documentation for `where()`.

```
dat |> 
    select(where(is.factor) | where(is.character))
```