# Selecting rows or columns by data type?

Tags: r, subset

Would it be possible to search for a column or row that matches a given type, such as `numeric` or `POSIXCT`?

For example, if you had a table like so:

`arizona.trees`:

```
arizona.trees
group redwoods   diameter    date 
A     23         2.19        2017-8-20 08:12:56                  
A     24         3.14        2017-8-22 08:15:54
B     9          5.16        2017-8-20 08:15:40
B     10         8.99        2017-8-21 18:15:45
C     88         7.30        2017-8-23 23:55:55
```

Would it be possible to try and search for all columns of type `POSICXT`, which would return the `date` column?

Comment: which(sapply(arizona.trees, class) == "POSIXct")

Comment: `sapply(arizona.trees, is.numeric)`

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/42951377/2204410 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/17964513/2204410

Answer (score 2):

You can get get the names of columns of a particular data type with

```
names(arizona.trees)[sapply(arizona.trees, is, "numeric")]
names(arizona.trees)[sapply(arizona.trees, is, "POSIXt")]
```

If you wanted to do something to those columns, the `dplyr` library has the `mutate_if`/`summarize_if`/`select_if` verbs

```
arizona.trees %>% select_if(is.numeric)
arizona.trees %>% summarize_if(is.numeric, mean)
```